# Intelhex - import error - macOSX Terminal

Tags: python, macos, import, terminal

I am using the terminal on a MacBook Pro.
Trying to use intelhex in my code. I have downloaded intelhex using

> sudo pip install intelhex

Success

> pip list

shows intelhex installed

run my code and receive this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "./myCode.py", line 20, in 
>       from intelhex import IntelHex
>   ImportError: No module named 'intelhex'

I am using Python 2.7.11

> ls /usr/local/bin

shows the contents of intelhex:

hex2bin.py

bin2hex.py

hexmerge.py

hexdiff.py

Where am I going wrong?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error means that there is no 'intelhex' on your Python path. The contents of /usr/local/bin should not matter (those are executable files but are not the Python modules). Are you sure that you installed the package and are loading it from the same Python site packages location you installed it to?

Comment: I installed the packages on python2 but my code was in python3. I used pip3 to install the intelhex there, now it works! thank You